# CSS or SVG Mask clip background with multiple svg

Tags: html, css, svg, clip-path

[image: How to make clipping mask of multiple svgs]

So the problem is: **How to do a css clipping mask of a div's background with multiple svgs?**

I have a video background which is looping. On top on the video i have a div with a black background as a semi-transparent overlay.

This background i want to do a mask clipping of 8 different svgs, so the icons will clip out the black background.

How can this be done? i tried doing a svg mask and also using the css3 clip-path, but i can't figure out to do this properly with multiple svgs?

UPDATE: Here is what i tried so far: https://jsfiddle.net/w1ft4jm1/

```
 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1920 1080" width="1920px" height="1080px" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" style="z-index: 6;">
<path transform="translate(820,350) scale(1.2)" id="XMLID_164_" class="st0" d="M153,48.4h21.8v87.7c0,33.3-27,60.3-60.3,60.3c-33.3,0-60.3-27-60.3-60.3V48.4H76v87.7
  c0,21.1,17.4,38.5,38.5,38.5c21.1,0,38.5-17.4,38.5-38.5V48.4z" fill="blue" stroke="blue" style="-webkit-filter: blur(10px); opacity: .5;"/>
<path transform="translate(820,350) scale(1.2)" id="XMLID_162_" fill="blue" stroke="blue" style="-webkit-filter: blur(10px); opacity: .5;" class="st0" d="M196.6,106h21.8v29.7c0,33.3-21.8,104.3-103.9,104.3S9.7,173.5,9.7,135.7V7.1h21.8
  c0,0,0,80,0,128.6c0,42.5,32.4,82.5,82.9,82.5s82.1-40,82.1-82.5C196.6,137.1,196.6,106,196.6,106z"/>

<defs>
  <mask id="mask" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" >
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%"/>
    <path transform="translate(820,350) scale(1.2)" id="XMLID_164_" class="st0" d="M153,48.4h21.8v87.7c0,33.3-27,60.3-60.3,60.3c-33.3,0-60.3-27-60.3-60.3V48.4H76v87.7
      c0,21.1,17.4,38.5,38.5,38.5c21.1,0,38.5-17.4,38.5-38.5V48.4z" stroke="blue"/>
    <path transform="translate(820,350) scale(1.2)" id="XMLID_162_" class="st0" d="M196.6,106h21.8v29.7c0,33.3-21.8,104.3-103.9,104.3S9.7,173.5,9.7,135.7V7.1h21.8
      c0,0,0,80,0,128.6c0,42.5,32.4,82.5,82.9,82.5s82.1-40,82.1-82.5C196.6,137.1,196.6,106,196.6,106z"/>
    </mask>
</defs>
<rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" style="opacity:.8;"/>
```

The problem is, i need to have multiple svg icons that is clipping the black background. And if i do everything as an SVG mask i will get issues to make it responsive.

What is the best way forward you think? Thanks!

Comment: Show us what you tried and explain exactly what it's limitations are and maybe we can correct it.

Comment: Sure, i have made a jsfiddle to explain what i did so far. Im thinking there has to be a better way?